# image transition with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, transition

Can anyone suggest a lightweight fading image transition for javascript or jquery.  I'm thinking something along the lines of this:

```
document.getElementById("foo").src="images/robin.jpg";
```

where the html looks like this:

```
<img id="foo" src="images/batman.png"/>
```

The problem here is that the image doesn't fade, rather changes immediately.  I can certainly stack and animate two images independently, but I'm trying to replace one image.  Just makes for tidier code.  Any advice is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no fading technique for javascript or css transitions that can do this in a tidy way. Two images seem the way to go.

Comment: @Roonaan I think I can do it with CSS ONLY

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it with pure CSS3? Use `transition, opacity` and `z-index` which will get you this effect with smooth effect

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQYks/)

CSS

```
div.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.wrap img {
    position: absolute;
}

div.wrap img:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}

div.wrap:hover img:nth-of-type(1) {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
}

div.wrap img:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}

div.wrap:hover img:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Update 2 : Initially I used `z-index` but I don't think we require that too..

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQYks/1/) (Without `z-index`)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but Demo 2 is damn slick.  I'll have to use that method in the future.

Comment: @user1497338 You can make it faster, just change `3s` to say `1s` http://jsfiddle.net/uQYks/2/